Access denied for signed url in big query
I have created a signed url in bigquery using EXTERNAL_OBJECT_TRANSFORM function. But the generated signed url gives access denied error. The service account has the necessary permissions.
Tried to provide elevated access to the service account but it still doesn't work.

Can you share how the query is trigger? Do you have access to the source file?

I have access to the files. I ran the query in GCP console.

How do you test the signedURL? How many time after the generation?
